# How to conditionally pull the latest tag of a Docker image, instead of using the cached version?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

My Dockerfile contains this line:

```
COPY --from=whatwg/wattsi:latest /whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi /bin/wattsi
```

i.e., it is copying an executable from the `whatwg/wattsi` image available on Docker Hub. This is essentially straight out of the documentation on [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

However, once I run the Dockerfile, it caches a local copy of `whatwg/wattsi:latest`. Then, any subsequent updates of `whatwg/wattsi` that get pushed to Docker Hub are ignored, and the cached copy is used. (I.e., this entire line just gets skipped, and the layer that it creates is reused.)

The behavior I would like is to have Docker compare the remote `whatwg/wattsi:latest` to the local cached copy, and re-download if there are differences. Is that possible?

I would like to do this without hard-coding a version for `whatwg/wattsi` into my Dockerfile, that needs to be updated every time `whatwg/wattsi` revs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker build` has a `--pull` option that will "always attempt to pull a newer version of the image."

*First build* (nothing cached)

```
Step 2/2 : COPY --from=whatwg/wattsi:latest /whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi /bin/watt
latest: Pulling from whatwg/wattsi
24f0c933cbef: Pull complete 
69e2f037cdb3: Pull complete 
4f7407c4e0dc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f555e4ff56b88313c7c47ca86b83367f9c1ca93552c477a96b9943e907bb7733
Status: Downloaded newer image for whatwg/wattsi:latest
 ---> 2ca5d7a1e784
```

*Second build* (uses cache)

```
Step 2/2 : COPY --from=whatwg/wattsi:latest /whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi /bin/watt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ca5d7a1e784
```

*Third build with `--pull`* (checks for updates)

```
Step 2/2 : COPY --from=whatwg/wattsi:latest /whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi /bin/watt
latest: Pulling from whatwg/wattsi
Digest: sha256:f555e4ff56b88313c7c47ca86b83367f9c1ca93552c477a96b9943e907bb7733
Status: Image is up to date for whatwg/wattsi:latest
 ---> 7d3390252ae1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no posibility how to write that in dockerfile.

But you can run

```
docker build --pull
```

From documentation

> `--pull` Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options

It is the same as running

```
docker pull whatwg/wattsi:latest
```

before your `docker build`. It just checks if your local copy of the image is up to date, and pulls newer version if not.

This problem exists not only for building but also for running them. Kubernetes solves that with `imagePullPolicy`. (See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)